# Unable to see the "Properties" option on right clicking the user database and column under the table in Azure Data Studio [ MAC SYSTEM ]

Tags: data-analysis, azure-data-studio, exploratory-data-analysis

Steps

1.Created a user database - DB1

2.Created a table - TB1 with **columns - cm1 and cm2**

3.Installed the  extension - "Database Administration Tool Extension"

4.Relaunched the application

**5.Right clicked on the database - DB1** ................................
**Observation** -> I could see some options like 'Manage' but not properties

**6.Right clicked on the column 'cm1' under the created table TB1**.........................
**Observation** -> I could see only refresh option but not properties

7.Additional Step: Tried searching for other relevant extension but couldn't spot.

**Question ->** How can I get the properties option enabled for DB and columns in AzureDataStudio in MAC System